# Empty $1 and $2 values Regex Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code:

```
my $sDatabase = "abc_def:xyz_comp.";
if ($sDatabase =~ m/^(\w)*\:(\w*)\_em\.$/)
{
    print "$1\:$2\.\n";
}
else
{
    print "$1\:$2\_em\.\n";
}
```

but I am getting empty `$1` and `$2`. The output is:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at new_mscn_iden_parse.pl line 187.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at new_mscn_iden_parse.pl line 187.
:_em.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will do what you want

```
my $sDatabase = "abc_def:xyz_comp.";

$sDatabase =~ m/^(\w+):(\w+?)(_em)?\.$/ or die "Invalid data";
if ($3) {
  print "$1:$2.\n";
}
else {
  print "$1:$2_em.\n";
}
```

Comment: if $sDatabase = "abc_def:xyz_comp_em." then i want $sDatabase = "abc_def:xyz_comp."

Please help.

Comment: How about just unconditionally `print "$1:$2$3.\n"` after surviving the m//?

Comment: Is `(\w+?)` a valid regular expression? I think you wanted `(\w+)?`.

Comment: @David W., no, what he wrote is correct. (That said, I despise the non-greediness modifier, though. Very fragile. You can't use it twice in the same pattern.)

Answer (score 3):

What do you expect `$1` and `$2` to contain when you fail to match?!

It contains whatever it contains before you attempted the match.

Possible solution:

```
$sDatabase =~ s/(?<!_em)(?=\.\z)/_em/;
```

Comment: $1 should have abc_def
$2 should have xyz_comp

Comment: How is that possible? The pattern didn't match.

Comment: But still i want a result in else condition then. Sorry if i am not making sense. How is that possible?

Comment: You're not listening. It's not possible. The match in `if (/.../) { ... } else { ... }` will not set `$1` when execution goes to the else branch, because you never told it what to place in `$1`. You can't use that pattern.

Comment: ok thanks. So how to assign "abc_def:xyz_comp." to variable if $sDatabase has value "abc_def:xyz_comp_em." and assign "abc_def:xyz_comp_em." if $sDatabase is equal to "abc_def:xyz_comp."

Comment: it gives me abc_def:xyz_comp_em_em. if  $sDatabase = "abc_def:xyz_comp_em.". I do not want that. In this case I want abc_def:xyz_comp.

Comment: Fixed the typo. Two of the chars had been flipped.

Comment: thanks for the help. =) Really appreciate that. All the replies to my stupid questions!

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
my $sDatabase = "abc_def:xyz_comp.";
if ($sDatabase =~ m/^(\w)*\:(\w*)\_em\.$/);
```

Let's see if this matches:

You're regular expression says:

- Anchor at the start of a line.
- You are looking for ***zero*** or more *word characters* . Word characters (in the ASCII alphabet) includes lowercase letters, uppercase letters ***numbers*** and ***underscores***.

  - Thus `/\w*/` will match all the following:
  - Computer
  - computer
  - computer23
  - computer_32
  - *an empty string*
- You're next looking for a colon
- Then, more word characters
- Followed by a `_em` string
- Followed by a period
- And that should be the end of the string (if there's no NL and you're not doing multi-line string searches. Looks like you're safe there).

Now, let's look at your string: `abc_def:xyz_comp.`

- `\w*` will match up to `abc_def`. Regular expressions are greedy and will try to match the biggest portion of the string as possible.
- The `:` will match the colon. So far, you're matching `abc_def:`.
- That `\w*` will match on `xyz_comp`.
- Now, you're trying to match a `_em`. Oops! No good. There is no `_em` in your string. Your regular expression match will fail.

Since your regular expression match fails, the `$1` and `$2` variables simply are not set and have no value.

That's why you're getting `Use of uninitialized value`. What you can do is make the later half of your expression *optional*:

```
my $sDatabase = "abc_def:xyz_comp.";
if ($sDatabase =~ /^(\w)+:(\w*)(_em)?\.$/) {
    if ( $3 ) {
        print "$1:${2}${3}.\n";
    else {
        print "$1:${2}_em.";
    }
}
else {
   die qq(String doesn't match regular expression at all\n);
}
```

}

First of all, I think you want to match at least **one** character (I could be wrong), so I switched the asterisk which matches zero or more to a `+` which matches one or more.

Note I have a third set of parentheses followed by a `?`. This means match this **zero or one** times. Thus, you will have a match, and `$1` and `$2` will be set as long as your string starts with one or more word characters, followed by a colon, followed by one or more word characters.

What won't necessarily happen is that `$3` will be set. This will only be set if your string also ends with `_em.`. If your string doesn't include the `_em`, but ends with a period, `$1` and `$2` will still match.

In your case, we could simplify it by doing this:

```
my $sDatabase = "abc_def:xyz_comp.";
if ($sDatabase =~ /^(\w)+:(\w*)(?:_em)?\.$/) {
    print "$1:${2}_em.";
else {
   die qq(String doesn't match regular expression at all\n);
}
```

The `(?:...)` means don't set a match, just group. Thus, `$3` will never be set. That's okay, either $3 is `_em.` or we add `_em.` to the end of the match anyway.

Comment: `(?:_em)?` will always match the empty string. You'll end up doubling `_em` if it's present.