# Perl: Empty $1 regex value when matching?

Tags: regex, perl, matching

Readers,

I have the following regex problem:

**code**

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use 5.010;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'input.txt';
open my $FILE, "<", $filename or die $!;

while (my $row = <$FILE>)
{                   # take one input line at a time
    chomp $row;
    if ($row =~ /\b\w*a\b/)
    {
       print "Matched: |$`<$&>$'|\n";  # the special match vars
       print "\$1 contains '$1' \n";
    }
    else
    {
       #print "No match: |$row|\n";
    }
}
```

### input.txt

```
I like wilma. 
this line does not match
```

### output

```
Matched: |I like <wilma>|
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at ./derp.pl line 14, <$FILE> line 22.
$1 contains ''
```

I am totally confused. If it is matching and I am checking things in a conditional. Why am I getting an empty result for $1? This isn't supposed to be happening. What am I doing wrong? How can I get `'wilma'` to be in $1?

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286318/empty-1-and-2-values-regex-perl) but this didn't help because I am getting a "match".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have any parentheses in your regex.  No parentheses, no $1.

I'm guessing you want the "word" value that ends in -a, so that would be `/\b(\w*a)\b/`.

Alternatively, since your whole regex only matches the bit you want, you can just use `$&` instead of `$1`, like you did in your debug output.

Another example:

```
my $row = 'I like wilma.';
$row =~ /\b(\w+)\b\s*\b(\w+)\b\s*(\w+)\b/;
print join "\n", "\$&='$&'", "\$1='$1'", "\$2='$2'", "\$3='$3'\n";
```

The above code produces this output:

```
$&='I like wilma'
$1='I'
$2='like'
$3='wilma'
```

Comment: @GeekyOmega: specifically, the parenthesis are creating a "capture group," and each such group is assigned to `$1,$2,$3,...`

Comment: `$&` "imposed a considerable performance penalty across the whole program, so generally the use of these variables has been discouraged." http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions

Comment: @chilemagic: "In Perl 5.20.0 a new copy-on-write system was enabled by default, which finally fixes all performance issues with these three variables, and makes them safe to use anywhere."  If you're using pre-5.20 and worried about the performance hit, using `/p` on the regex will mitigate it.

Comment: @MarkReed This answer is amazing.

Comment: @MarkReed Thank you. Stupid question though. Why must (\w*a) be in a parenthesis? Is it like this each () corresponds to $1? So in general ()() corresponds to $1 and $2?

Comment: @GeekyOmega: that is correct, as in my first comment on this answer.

Comment: Yes.  You can always get the whole match in `$&`, but if you want specific parts of the match, you have to indicate which parts you want.  Just given an arbitrary regular expression, there's no way for Perl to know which parts of it you care about remembering separately.  You have to indicate that somehow, and the way you do so is with parentheses.