# Print the matched string in Perl pattern match

Tags: perl

```
use strict;

my $type = "build";
if ($type =~ (/build|test/))
{
   print "type=$1";
}
```

I expect it to print "type=build", but $1 gets nothing and it prints "type=", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this post can help you to get an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936145/perl-empty-1-regex-value-when-matching

Comment: Hint: `use warnings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not capturing anything with your parentheses,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e'
  use strict;

  my $type = "build";
  if ($type =~ (/build|test/))
  {
     print "type=$1";
  }
  '
```

output

```
use strict;
my $type = 'build';
if ($type =~ /build|test/) {
    print "type=$1";
}
```

but `/(build|test)/` should be completely another story.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here. Are you simply demonstrating that the parentheses make no difference? That doesn't seem to be a solution to the question.

Comment: Yes, and solution is suggested at the end of the answer.

Comment: Okay. But *“`/(build|test)/` should be completely another story”* doesn't look a lot like a proposed solution, or even a recommendation!

Comment: @Cyxon27, Thanks for showing Deparse feature, but it throws below error when I try to check the same, I got the answer to my problem, but like to know how to use Deparse.
  `C:\>perl -MO=Deparse -e 'use strict; my $type = "build"; if ($type =~ (/build|test/))  { print "type=$1"; }'`
_Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.  test: extra argument `'_

Comment: @Krish under win you'll have to use `perl -e ".."`, and `qq()` instead of `""`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't capturing anything inside your regex. Your parentheses need to be *inside* the pattern, like this

```
if ( $type =~ /(build|test)/ ) {
    print "type=$1";
}
```

Comment: @Krish : If this solved your problem, accept this as an answer and close this.

Answer (score 1):

That is the reason people here suggest to use `use warnings` and `use strict`.
If you add `use warnings` in your code you will get a warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at type.pl line 7
```

code is :

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $type = "build";
if ($type =~ /(build|test)/)
{
   print "type=$1";
}
```